# Subject followed by infinitive — what is the grammatical name for this structure?

Tags: infinitives, subjects

Example sentence:

"Germany to raise prices ...", which usually can be used as "Germany (is) set to raise prices ..." but the first example is also correct. Can you help me with explanation or link to resource about this sentence structure?

Comment: You're comparing headlinese to English. New! Improved! It is the job of headlines to condense, tease, and be all around sexy.

Comment: Can you provide the entire sentence? If it’s just “Germany to raise prices”, then that sounds like “headlinese”.

Comment: The example is this tweet: https://mobile.twitter.com/BNONews/status/1510680428587401219 "BREAKING: German food retailers to raise prices by 20-50% on Monday, says German Retail Association"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"A Student's Grammar of The English Language"* by Sidney Greenbaum Randolph Quirk 2016, describes such phrases, clauses, etc., as **block language**

In basic terms, block language minimises the number of words to a point at which the native reader would still understand the general meaning.

> 11.22 Block language appears (especially in writing) in such functions as labels, titles, newspaper headlines, headings, notices, and advertisements. Simple block-language messages often consist of a noun phrase in isolation:
>
> Entrance 50 mph limit
>
> English Department
>
> The New York Times
>
> For Sale
>
> No dogs without leash
>
> **Newspaper headlines commonly contain block language because of pressure on space, and they are imitated on radio and television news broadcasts. They can often be analysed in terms of clause structure, but with the omission of words that may be understood from the context, such as the finite forms of the verb be and the articles:**
>
> OIL SPILL THREAT DECREASING [SV]
>
> PRESIDENT CALLS FOR CALM [SVA]
>
> SHARE PRICES NOW HIGHER [SAC]
>
> **Sentence types and discourse functions**
>
> Omissions of words that can be inferred from the context occur in other types of writing:
>
> Wish you were here, [postcard]
>
> MANUSCRIPT RECEIVED CHANGES ACCEPTED [cable]
>
> Refrigerate after opening [label]
>
> NOTE [a] Notices of prohibition often take the form of a noun phrase introduced by No: No entry ; No smoking .
>
> [b] In informal conversation many types of phrases occur as complete utterances: The things they get up to !; You and your ideas !; Of all the stupid things to say !; Taxi !; More coffee ?; Your name ?; No news. In addition there are many formulae used for stereotyped communication situations; for example: Good morning ; Goodbye ; How do you do ?; Thanks ; Happy Birthday.
>
> [c] Interjections are purely emotive words which do not enter into syntactic relations. Among the common interjections are Ah, Boo, Oh, Ouch, Sh, Wow.

Comment: Thanks for this information. So this is not proper English grammar, but still common used language in these "news headlines" contexts. Good to know.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a case of “[qualifying infinitive](https://www.english-grammar-today.com/qualifying-infinitive.html)”:

> When the infinitive is used to qualify a noun, verb or adjective, it is called a qualifying infinitive or gerundial infinitive.

Comment: No, it is not. The given example would be a sentence with a finite verb if it were normal proces; but as others have pointed out, it is headlinese.